# another vertical align issue inside a div

Tags: html, css

i can never seem to get the vertical align attribute to work. i have a simple div with a small picture inside it (40px high) and i need the text to align vertically in the middle. can somebody shed some light on what im doing wrong here? thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="back"><img src="../../images/back-button-1.jpg" style="padding-right:10px;" width="40" height="40" alt="back" />Back</div>
```

CSS:

```
#back{
width:auto;
height:40px;
background:#C36;
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#333333;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "line-height" set to the height of the container on an inline element works well in this case as well, but only if it is one line of text.

Answer (score 3):

Add this rule:

```
#back img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LuYx7/)**